# Ease/Support of adding APB (ASP.NET Boilerplate) to an existing ASP.NET Core project

Tags: asp.net, aspnetboilerplate

I am very interested in some of the features in Asp.Net Boilerplate (https://aspnetboilerplate.com/), but we have an existing Asp.Net Core 2.1 application.

In the docs for this project I wasn't able to find any discussion about adding APB to an existing Asp.Net application, so I'm hoping to get clarity into:

```
a) Whether adding APB to an existing project is a supported use-case.

b) What the steps for installing it into an existing project would look like.
```

Comment: I would suggest creating a new application with APB and then copying over what you need/want. Or the other way around if your current application isn't too big already.

Comment: It depends on the features you need from Abp, first issue you probably face is with dependency injection if you are using a different DI (abp relies on castle.winsdor heavily)

Comment: If you need Module Zero, then you would need to resolve User/Role/Tenant models with your existing identity models